# Override GITHUB_TOKEN provided by Github Action

Tags: github-actions

According to the Github Actions [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication), GitHub automatically automatically creates a token (`GITHUB_TOKEN`) to use in our workflow. Is it possible to override this token by our ?

I tried to add it as a secret but we can't add secrete starting by `GITHUB_`. I also tried to change the environment variable `GITHUB_TOKEN` but without success.